# Android/sencha/phonegap ajax call to local php file returns whole code?

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch

just wondering if anyone give me a bit of support here. I'm using phonegap to run a sencha app on an android phone. In the code I'm making an ajax call to a php file stored locally to check if a file exists......

```
   myRequest = Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'resources/phpScripts/poifound.php',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                    pakname: packname,
                    poiident: poiid
                    },
                    success: function(response) {

                    console.log(response.responseText);


                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                    console.log("failed");
                    }
                });
```

And the php file......

```
<?php
   $pakname = $_GET["pakname"];
   $poiid= $_GET["poiident"];

   if (!file_exists('../../packages/' . $pakname .'/poisfound/' . $pakname . $poiid . '.txt')) {
    return "false";   
   }
   else {
    return "true";
   }

?>
```

Instead of it logging either 'true' or 'false' in the LogCat it is actually logging the entire php code instead. When running the sencha app in chrome it returns 'true' or 'false' with echo instead of return. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because, you package a PHP file onto an android device. There is no PHP interpreter on android. You'll need a Server, which runs you PHP.

```
 myRequest = Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'http://myserver.com/resources/phpScripts/poifound.php',
                method: 'GET', [...]
```

And to make you life easier you will need to add you server to the whitelist: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html